# PHP - Read value from Current array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$data = array (
  "card" => array(
               "id" => $_GET["id"],
               "user" => dynamicFunction($_GET["id"]),
               "Origin" => $data["card"]["user"]
));
```

I'm getting an error here.

**How can I read the value from current array element `user` without calling `dynamicFunction` again since that function will execute DB query again.** I don't want to overload my SQL server with unnecessary queries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @u_mulder : I don't think it's same as Undefined variable. I'm looking for a solution which will help me in reading element from current array.
**I m not trying to read from an undeclared variable**

Comment: Currently you have syntax error. replace $_GET("id") with  $_GET["id"]

Comment: `$var = dynamicFunction($_GET["id"])`;

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Typo. But still my problem remains the same with element `origin`

Comment: Update question. How you accessing your array elements.

Comment: @Adnanhaider Already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$user = dynamicFunction($_GET["id"]);
$data = array (
    "card" => array(
        "id" => $_GET["id"],
        "user" => $user,
        "Origin" => $user,
));
```

Option 2:

```
$data = array (
    "card" => array(
        "id" => $_GET["id"],
        "user" => dynamicFunction($_GET["id"]),
));
$data["card"]['Origin'] = $data["card"]['user'];
```

Option 3:

```
$data = array (
    "card" => array(
        "id" => $_GET["id"],
        "user" => $user = dynamicFunction($_GET["id"]),
        "Origin" => $user,
));
```

And no, you cannot access item af array which is not yet initialized.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please suggest which one is performance optimized?

Comment: Optimization is useless here. You won't gain anything. Choose variant that will be understandable when you will read your code 5-6 months later.

Comment: Well, I'll go with Option 3 then